# Confirm Dialog with options

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I need some instructions on the best way to do this, I have some pseudo code.

```
/*form needs to be a drop down as below*/
//    -------------------------------
//   |                          X   |
//    -------------------------------
//   |     "chose your option"      |
//   |                              |
//   |       [choice 1 [v]]         |
//   |                              |
//   |   [ok]         [cancel]      |
//    -------------------------------

int optionchosen = confirmoptionbox();
if (optionchosen==1){
    //do something
}
if (optionchosen==2){
    // do something else
}
if (optionchosen==3){
    // third way
}
//etc etc
```

Now, I know how to do that with a new form (etc etc) but I was genuinely wondering if there was a more "elegant" option that doesn't involve heaps of things

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: sorry, yes - I thought the tag "visual-studio-2010" I had used would not have been ambiguous I am concerned with "Visual C# 2010 Express" (is that "WinForms"?)

Comment: You can have both winforms and WPF in Visual C# 2010 Express, in both cases though, you're probably gonna have to write your own custom form.

Answer (score 1):

design a form .open it up as a modal window and get value from NewForm

```
NewForm nf=new NewForm();

nf.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sincerly I don't see where is the problem writing the form by yourself. However the pseudocode you wrote is almost perfect, infact it is the best way of doing it. Althought your pseudocode could be improved as I'm going to write. 
Speaking of the form you could structure it in this way to make it *reusable*:

```
class myForm : Form{
    public int Result;

    private Label lblText;
    private Button btnOk, btnCancel;
    private CheckBox[] checkboxes;     

    public myForm(string text, params string[] choicesText){
        //set up components
        lblText = new Label(){
           Text = text,
           AutoSize = true,
           Location = new Point(10, 10)
           //...
        };

        checkboxes = new CheckBox[choicesText.Length];
        int locationY = 30;
        for(int i = 0; i < checkboxes.Length; i++){
           checkboxes[i] = new CheckBox(){
               Text = choicesText[i],
               Location = new Point(10, locationY),
               Name = (i + 1).ToString(),
               AutoSize = true,
               Checked = false
               //...
           };

           locationY += 10;
        }

        btnOk = new Button(){
           Text = "OK",
           AutoSize = true,
           Location = new Point(20, locationY + 20)
           //...
        };

        btnOk += new EventHandler(btnOk_Click);
        //and so on 

        this.Controls.AddRange(checkboxes);
        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{ lblText, btnOk, btnCancel /*...*/ });
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Result = checkboxes.Where(x => x.Checked == true).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
        this.Close();
    }      
}
```

Then in the main form:

```
using(myForm form = new myForm("Select a choice", "choice 1", "choice 2")){
   form.ShowDialog();
   int result = form.Result;
   switch(result){
     case 1: MessageBox.Show("You checked choice 1") ; break;
     case 2: MessageBox.Show("You checked choice 2") ; break;
     default: MessageBox.Show("Invalid choice"); break;
   }
}
```

**PS:**

Here I used checkboxes but you can change it and add a combobox with a dropdown style, and then you will have what you need.